# Node native mongodb driver connection pool issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rxjs

I'm using Node.js + RxJS + MongoDB for socket.io server. After a certain number of requests my connection pool to DB becomes incredibly large. So file descriptors are never released and server goes down.

For db queries I use following code:

```
/* @flow */

var { Observable } = require('rx');
var client = require('mongodb');
var { assign } = require('lodash');
var __DEV__ = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
var URL = 'my database url';

class QueryBuilder {
  _db$: Observable;
  _selectors: Object;

  constructor(db$: Observable, selectors?: Object) {
    this._db$ = db$;

    if (!selectors) {
      this._selectors = assign({
        collection: null,
        query: {},
        opts: {},
        sort: {},
        offset: 0,
        limit: 0
      }, selectors);
    }
    else {
      this._selectors = selectors;
    }
  }

  static connect(url: string): QueryBuilder {
    var connect = Observable.fromNodeCallback(client.connect, client);
    var db$ = connect(db.url);

    db$.subscribe(
      _ => {
        if (__DEV__) {
          console.log('Connected to database on', url);
        }
      },
      err => console.log('Database connection error:', err.message, err.stack)
    );

    return new QueryBuilder(db$);
  }

  close(): any {
    this._db$.dispose();

    return QueryBuilder;
  }

  collection(name: string): QueryBuilder {
    var ss = assign({}, this._selectors, { collection: name });
    return new QueryBuilder(this._db$, ss);
  }

  select(query?: Object = {}, opts?: Object = {}): QueryBuilder {
    var ss = assign({}, this._selectors, { query, opts });
    return new QueryBuilder(this._db$, ss);
  }

  selectOne(query?: Object = {}, opts?: Object = {}): QueryBuilder {
    var ss = assign({}, this._selectors, {
      query: query,
      opts: opts,
      limit: 1
    });
    return new QueryBuilder(this._db$, ss);
  }

  sort(sort: Object): QueryBuilder {
    var ss = assign({}, this._selectors, { sort });
    return new QueryBuilder(this._db$, ss);
  }

  skip(offset: number): QueryBuilder {
    var ss = assign({}, this._selectors, { offset });
    return new QueryBuilder(this._db$, ss);
  }

  limit(limit: number = 0): QueryBuilder {
    var ss = assign({}, this._selectors, { limit });
    return new QueryBuilder(this._db$, ss);
  }

  exec(): Observable {
    var ss = this._selectors;
    var db$ = this._db$

    if (!ss.collection) return Observable.throw('You have to provide collection name.');
    if (!db$) return Observable.throw('No db connection found.');

    var o = db$.flatMapLatest(db => {
      var c = db.collection(ss.collection);
      var cursor = c.find(ss.query, ss.opts).sort(ss.sort).skip(ss.offset).limit(ss.limit);
      var obs = Observable.fromNodeCallback(cursor.toArray, cursor);
      return obs();
    });

    return ss.limit === 1 ? o.map(res => res[0]) : o;
  }
}

module.exports = QueryBuilder.connect(URL);
```

Where is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking the subscription in the `connect` method and you are disposing the observable instead of the subscription.

```
class QueryBuilder {
  _db$: Observable;
  _sub: Disposable;
  _selectors: Object;

  constructor(db$: Observable, selectors?: Object) {
    this._db$ = db$;

    this._sub = db$.subscribe(
      _ => {
        if (__DEV__) {
          console.log('Connected to database on', url);
        }
      },
      err => console.log('Database connection error:', err.message, err.stack)
    );

    if (!selectors) {
      this._selectors = assign({
        collection: null,
        query: {},
        opts: {},
        sort: {},
        offset: 0,
        limit: 0
      }, selectors);
    }
    else {
      this._selectors = selectors;
    }
  }

  static connect(url: string): QueryBuilder {
    var connect = Observable.fromNodeCallback(client.connect, client);
    var db$ = connect(db.url);

    return new QueryBuilder(db$);
  }

  close(): any {
    this._sub.dispose();

    return QueryBuilder;
  }
}
```

(Untested)